# Remove the colored section box from moderncv

Tags: boxes, moderncv

Using `moderncv` as follows;

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{casual}
```

I'd like to remove the coloured struts/rectangles/boxes, adjacent to section headings, from the output.

Can someone please tell me how to do this? I have previously used latex only for article writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write after your given two lines to change the color of the leading box to white:

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{255,255,255}   % color white
\makeatletter                             % make @ a letter
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{mycolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

This workaround runs with the styles `casual` and `classic` but not with `banking`.
I changed only the used color from `\color{color1}` to `\color{mycolor}` and set `mycolor` to `white`.
The original definition of macro section you can find in the file `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`.

Have you checked the style `banking`? This style does not use colored boxes.

## Update to class `moderncv`, version 2.0.0 (current version):

with the current class `moderncv`, version 2.0.0 the definition in style `casual` has changed to:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
```

Therefore we need to use command `\RenewDocumentCommand` to redefine `\color{color1}` to `\color{white}`. Please note that a patch with command `\patchcmd` is **not working**, commands defined with `\RenewDocumentCommand` are not patchable!

We need to add the following code into the preamble (`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed because the code uses `@`):

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{white}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy  % head 2, body 1, foot 1
\moderncvcolor{black} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{white}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{70pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\end{document}
```

you get your wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 6):

Adding

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\section}% <cmd>
  {\strut}% <search>
  {\strut\renewcommand{\raisebox}[2]{}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

to your document preamble removes the boxes altogether by making the `\raisebox` command equivalent to a no-op, thereby gobbling its two arguments. This redefinition of `\raisebox` is local, since it is executing inside a `\parbox`.

The output below is obtained using the `casual` template ([`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex)) with a `black` style and using the image [`example-image-16x10`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-16x10.pdf) (from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)) for the `\photo`:

[image]

Comment: Clever workaround!

Comment: This did not work for me, but the other answer did. Any ideas of why this does not work now? Has the moderncv package changed since this was posted?

Comment: @matsr: Yes, it seems that way. I'll fix this later.