# Removing the colored boxes from sections in moderncv

Tags: boxes, moderncv

I want to get rid of the colored boxes that appear when starting a new section in `moderncv`. I found this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63432/remove-the-colored-section-box-from-moderncv) but none of the presented solutions achieved what I wanted.

See the MWE below for the solutions in one document for testing.

Solution 1 worked fine at doing what it is meant to do, setting the color of the bar to white. But it is still present and consumes space, while I would prefer a formatting pretty similar to the "standard"-section with the sectionname flushed left (but no number as this does not make any sense in a cv).

Solution 2 gives the error

> File `moderncvcolorwhite.sty' not found. ^^M

Also this solution would also just set the color to white.

And Solution 3 does not give an error but also does not have any (visible) effect.

I found on [this](http://matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=113073&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de) site (sadly in german) the definition of the sections in `moderncv.cls` (Careful, I am not sure how trustworthy this is!). My attempts to simply remove the box produced lots of errors.

Can anyone help?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.4cm, right=1.0cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{comment}
\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}

%===============================================
%Solution 1
\begin{comment}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{255,255,255}   % color white
\makeatletter                             % make @ a letter
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{white}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
\end{comment}

%====================================================
%Solution 2
%\begin{comment}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1,1,1}
}
\moderncvcolor{white}
%\end{comment}

%=================================================
%Solution 3
%\begin{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\section}% <cmd>
  {\strut}% <search>
  {\strut\renewcommand{\raisebox}[2]{}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
%\end{comment}


%=======================================
%Snippet from moderncv.cls
\begin{comment}
\newcommand*{\section}[1]{%
    \vspace*{2.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \parbox[m]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\raggedleft\hintfont{\color{sectionrectanglecolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{1ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[m]{\maincolumnwidth}{\sectionstyle{#1}}\\[1ex]}
\end{comment}
%====================================

\firstname{Homer Jay}
\familyname{Simpson}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{742 Evergreen Terrace}{Springfield}
\mobile{1234/56789}
\email{homerjaysimpson@groening.com}
\begin{document}
  \makecvtitle

\section{Personal Data}
  \cvitem{Family status}{married}
  \cvitem{Nationality}{US-American}
  \cvitem{Date of birth}{1956-05-12}
  \cvitem{Place of birth}{Springfield}

\section{Education}
  \cventry{1960 -- 1970}{Elementary School}{}{}{}{}


  \vfill
  Homer Jay Simpson\\
  Springfield, \today
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about this [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180131/moderncv-remove-horizontal-line-in-sections) ?

Comment: Oh I haven´t found that post, this is what I am looking for. Thank you. But there is one issue that disturbs me a bit: When starting a new section, the spacing is different from the default one; now it looks a bit scrambled. Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: You want to add space between section ? : `\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
 \vspace{1cm}\strut\sectionstyle{#2\hfill}%
 \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading
}` where you can change the value of the argument of the `\vspace` command.

Comment: Hmm this gives me the error  `You can't use "\spacefactor" in vertical mode \section{Personal Data}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that `moderncv` is designed to have a first and a second column (see red line in the following resulting pdf).

What you want to do is to break the good design completely. I would **not** recommend this.

For a workaround you can define the following new command `\mysection`:

```
\newcommand*{\mysection}[1]{%
  \vspace{2.5ex}% \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  % ... deleted
  \parbox[m]{\textwidth}{\sectionstyle{#1}}\\[1ex]}
```

Please notice the changes in line two and the last line, also see that I deeted some lines.

With the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
  left=2.4cm, right=1.0cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=2.0cm,
  showframe
]{geometry}

\moderncvtheme[black]{classic} % banking classic casual

%===============================================
%Solution 1
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{255,255,255}   % color white
\makeatletter                             % make @ a letter
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \parbox[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{white}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[t]{\maincolumnwidth}{\strut\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mysection}[1]{%
  \vspace{2.5ex}% \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \parbox[m]{\textwidth}{\sectionstyle{#1}}\\[1ex]}


\firstname{Homer Jay}
\familyname{Simpson}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{742 Evergreen Terrace}{Springfield}
\mobile{1234/56789}
\email{homerjaysimpson@groening.com}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Personal Data}
\cvitem{Family status}{married}
\cvitem{Nationality}{US-American}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{1956-05-12}
\cvitem{Place of birth}{Springfield}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1960 -- 1970}{Elementary School}{}{}{}{}

\vspace{2.5ex}
\mysection{Personal Data to test a longer line to see what happens if the line breaks into two lines}
\cvitem{Family status}{married}
\cvitem{Nationality}{US-American}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{1956-05-12}
\cvitem{Place of birth}{Springfield}

\mysection{Education}
\cventry{1960 -- 1970}{Elementary School}{}{}{}{}

\vfill
Homer Jay Simpson\\
Springfield, \today
\end{document}
```

you can see the resulting typing area (option `showframe`) in the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

That does not look pretty and I suggest to use another class or use `article` with own designs ...